# Why am I getting 404s for existing source apt repositories in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management

When I issue `apt-get update` I get

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Err http://ftp.port80.se precise-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ftp.port80.se precise-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ftp.port80.se precise-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
...
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.port80.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.port80.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.port80.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
```

There are other source lines that are properly updated. And relevant sources.list lines are

```
...
deb-src http://ftp.port80.se/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.port80.se/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://ftp.port80.se/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
...
```

I also notice that `http://ftp.port80.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources` doesn't exist, but `http://ftp.port80.se/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources.gz` does. I assume that `*.gz` should be tried before giving up?

**Could anyone explain to me why I'm getting 404s for these repositories?**

Maybe of interest:

- I am using an HTTP proxy to access this mirror.
- The `/etc/apt/sources.list` is in its original form, except all occurrences of `se.archive.ubuntu.com` have been replaced by `ftp.port80.se/ubuntu/`.
- Just to be sure I've tested doing `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and `apt-get update`. Still, the same problem.
- Since this is "12.04 LTS", this is not an issue with an End-of-life Ubuntu release.

Comment: Meh, that was a typo. Double checked against output and corrected question. Sorry about that.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-config dump` Also correct the lines containing `precise.updates` etc

Comment: @Anwar Corrected the typo. You can find the `apt-config dump` output here: https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/ebcbdb4440e4a68dab93371ffa174fe2 Also, I've recreated this on a machine that doesn't use HTTP proxy. Replacing `ftp.port80.se` with `ftp.acc.umu.se` (another mirror) seem to fix the issue.

Comment: So the issue is fixed?

Comment: Yes sand no. I found a workaround. I'm still curious to understand why ftp.port80.se failed.